# Create map for user 'userId' as a key and all post come together in array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I know the title might sounds confusing, but I'm stuck for an hour, mainly how to put them in array. This is my mongo output-

`userFavPost`:

```
 [ { post: '2920', user: '5a1d2f59cf81657f613b0683' },
   { post: '2920', user: '5a057915c31eb5601da9b75f' },
   { post: '2922', user: '5a057915c31eb5601da9b75f' },
   { post: '2998', user: '5a057915c31eb5601da9b75f' } ]
```

I want to create map, so that I will get data like this -

```
{
  '5a1d2f59cf81657f613b0683' => {
    post: [2920],
    user: '5a1d2f59cf81657f613b0683'
  },
  '5a057915c31eb5601da9b75f' => {
    post: [2920, 2922, 2998],
    user: '5a057915c31eb5601da9b75f'
  }
}
```

I know this is a newbie question but I'm confused!

Comment: Don't dump the output, what  have  you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Use array.reduce  function and in the accumulator object check if there exist a key same as the user value. If it exist , then push the new value in the array , otherwise create a new key by user value and push the post value into the array

```js
let arr = [{
    post: '2920',
    user: '5a1d2f59cf81657f613b0683'
  },
  {
    post: '2920',
    user: '5a057915c31eb5601da9b75f'
  },
  {
    post: '2922',
    user: '5a057915c31eb5601da9b75f'
  },
  {
    post: '2998',
    user: '5a057915c31eb5601da9b75f'
  }
]

let newObj = arr.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  if (acc.hasOwnProperty(curr.user)) {
    acc[curr.user].push(curr.post)
  } else {

    acc[curr.user] = [curr.post]

  }

  return acc;
}, {});


console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another take, that produces the form specified in the original post:

```
const userFavPost =
 [ { post: '2920', user: '5a1d2f59cf81657f613b0683' },
   { post: '2920', user: '5a057915c31eb5601da9b75f' },
   { post: '2922', user: '5a057915c31eb5601da9b75f' },
   { post: '2998', user: '5a057915c31eb5601da9b75f' } ];

const postMap = userFavPost.reduce((users, entry) => ({
  ...users,
  [entry.user]: {
    ...users[entry.user],
    user: entry.user,
    post: [
      ...(users[entry.user] && users[entry.user].post || []),
      entry.post
    ]
  }
}), {});

/* { '5a1d2f59cf81657f613b0683': 
       { user: '5a1d2f59cf81657f613b0683', post: [ '2920' ] },
     '5a057915c31eb5601da9b75f':
       { user: '5a057915c31eb5601da9b75f', post: [ '2920', '2922', '2998' ] } 
   } */
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use as simple [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with destructuring like this:

```js
const posts= [{post:'2920',user:'5a1d2f59cf81657f613b0683'},{post:'2920',user:'5a057915c31eb5601da9b75f'},{post:'2922',user:'5a057915c31eb5601da9b75f'},{post:'2998',user:'5a057915c31eb5601da9b75f'}]
   
const merged = posts.reduce((acc, {user,post}) => {
    // check if user already exists in the accumulator else create
    acc[user] = acc[user] || {user, post:[]} 
    acc[user]["post"].push(post)
    return acc
  }, {});
  
console.log(merged)
```

You could do all that in one line like this:

```js
const posts= [{post:'2920',user:'5a1d2f59cf81657f613b0683'},{post:'2920',user:'5a057915c31eb5601da9b75f'},{post:'2922',user:'5a057915c31eb5601da9b75f'},{post:'2998',user:'5a057915c31eb5601da9b75f'}]
   
const merged = posts.reduce((acc, {user,post}) =>
  ((acc[user] = acc[user] || {user, post:[]})["post"].push(post), acc),{});
  
console.log(merged)
```